# Read npm start console output in Python

Tags: python, node.js

I have a nodejs application that can be started using npm start command.I need to call the npm start from a python script.Once the script successfully started the application,i need to read all the lines in the console.

For example once i start the application using npm start,the console will show me "Development server running in port 9000".

How do read the line "Development server running in port 9000" from the console and write it in a text file using python.

Comment: why don't you just pipe the output from  `node start` to the output file? Like `node start > node_log.txt`?

Comment: But i want to do some processing before storing as a text  file.